# Windows Azure web site in free mode outbound data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

All, I had deployed a website in Windows Azure which I can upload and download file from it, the file is stored in the Windows Azure Storage Blob. And I note in the free mode the max outbound data per day is 165 MB, and inbound data is unlimited as [Price detail](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#web-sites) mentioned. So I want to know what happen to the website if the amount of outbound data exceed the 165MB. Because the max size of file which is upload or download in my website will be lager than 200MB. I didn't see any price detail about this situation. and also worry about if the website can works well in this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the free site will stop working if the size is exceeded. If you need that much you may want to consider the Shared option for ~10$ a month during preview. The Shared option will not throttle you when you exceed 165MB, you will just be charged for what you consume.

Comment: If I serve the blob directly from blob storage instead of through website, will that be included in 165 MB quota or is that separate?

Comment: Where can I find related reference document in MSDN for this issue?

Comment: Hi, Gaurav, The issue i mentioned here is about the outbound data of Website, So , seems your question is nothing to do with 165MB. Did I misunderstood you? thanks

Comment: I was thinking if you're storing the file in blob storage, you may be able to serve it directly from blob storage instead of serving it through your application. That's the reason I asked the question from Nir that if we serve it from blob storage, will it or not be included in this 165 MB limit. My guess is No, but let's hear from Nir.

Comment: Is it better choice to use Cloud Service? Our team is charge for Azure  in the Pay-as-you-go mode. Some project is deployed in Cloud services. I don't know which choice is better for my application. Nir, Hope you can give some advise . thanks.